# QFT decay rates in lower dimensions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, spacetime-dimensions, fermions, higgs

My starting point is the decay of a Higgs particle into two fermions, with decay rate proportional to
\begin{equation}
\Gamma \propto g_\psi^2 N m,
\end{equation}
where $g_\psi$ is the coupling, $N$ is the number of fermion flavours and $m$ the mass of the Higgs particle.

I derived this result in $3+1$ dimensional QFT, as usual. Can I in principle consider the same decay also in $1+1$ or $2+1$ dimensions?

I know that in $1+1$ dimensions quantized gauge fields have no dynamical degrees of freedom, even though the theory can be formally written down. In $2+1$ dimensions, there occur no problems, as far as I know.

Is the Higgs decay rate analogous in $1+1$ and $2+1$ dimensions, only with a modified coupling where the initially dimensionless coupling gets promoted to a coupling with mass dimension $1/2$ ($2+1$ dim.) or $1$ ($1+1$ dim.)?